# launch GUI app from QProcess

Tags: qt, qprocess

I want to launch GUI app using QProcess.

process.start() return immediately without showing GUI app window.

I also tried CONFIG += console .It didn't work.

```
QProcess process;
process.setEnvironment(QProcess::systemEnvironment());
process.start("pkexec --user root ",QStringList()<<QString("apt-get install xyz"));
process.waitForFinished();
process.close();
```

Comment: Can you show the code that you're using to attempt to launch the GUI app?

Comment: You'll need to tell us more. What exactly was the call to `QProcess::start`?  Can you get any type of process to start or is it just GUI ones that fail?

Comment: start is calling pkexec(which has GUI)(to give admin rights to apt-get command)
pkexec prompts for a password.

Comment: You didn't check for errors in your code :)  Maybe the reason it returns "immediately" is that the command immediately fails to execute.  Before doing anything else, add error checking.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
process.start("pkexec", QStringList() << "--user" << "root" << "apt-get" << "install" << "xyz");
```

Comment: @smitpatel24: This worked for me if I substituted `xeyes` for `pkexec` and some suitable options. I didn't have `pkexec` installed so I couldn't test that. I assume that `pkexec --user root apt-get install xyz` works from the command line for you?