# running apt-get by using Qt (QProcess)

Tags: c++, qt, shell, ubuntu, apt-get

I want to install and run some shell script by using Qt and make a Ubuntu Desktop Application.
now I use:

```
QProcess process;
process.startDetached("bash /home/root_enable");
process.waitForFinished(-1);
```

But I don't see terminal to enter Y/n and other command.
How can I fix this problem?

**my root_enable is:**

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Comment: please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258565/launch-gui-app-from-qprocess

Comment: another question startDetached will detach from current Process, Please use start

Comment: None of theme help me I need external terminal.

Comment: misunderstanding.. so you are not writing a console qt application.

Comment: In windows when I use process and run cmd I get cmd but in ubuntu no.

Answer (score 1):

**QProcess** inherits **QIODevice**. You can use any of its write methods to write to the input stream of the process.

Connect to *readyReadStandardOutput* signal of the process. In the handler read standard output, parse it and decide what to answer if needed.

Comment: I can not do this job I need external terminal.

Comment: @Hamed, @N0un`s answer should work. you need connect to the detached process and send your passwd. Or the process will be blocked waiting your root passwd input.

Comment: @Hamed It should. Edit your post and show us some code if possible ?

Comment: @Hamed Well, you say my idea doesn't work so you can show me how you tried it if you want

Comment: @N0un I don't know how to do it.